# IntelliJ Idea 10.5.2 WebLogic Deployment tab is missing context dropdown

Tags: intellij-idea, weblogic

IntelliJ Idea 10.5.0 WebLogic Run/Debug configuration [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-weblogic.html) mentions context dropdown. I am using 10.5.2 version and cannot find this dropdown. Is there a way to configure application context without editing application server specific descriptor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it is mistake in documentation. There is no such option for WebLogic run configurations.